# Oracle SQL Developer - Declare a variable once

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and running my query in a worksheet as a script.

What I wanted to happen is to be prompted to declare the value once.

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN (&age);
SELECT * FROM Job WHERE min_age IN (&age);
```

However, when I run the query, it prompts me to enter a value for my variable twice.

I have tried to define it at the top.
I have tried to use &&age in my second query.
I tried to use :age instead.

But each time I have to declare it twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear stored substitution variables in Oracle SQL developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267341/how-to-clear-stored-substitution-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701770/using-a-temporary-variable-once-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&&age` for both references:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN (&&age);
SELECT * FROM Job WHERE min_age IN (&&age);
```

If you want to re-run the script and still be prompted (once) on each run then undefine the variable first:

```
undefine age
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN (&&age);
SELECT * FROM Job WHERE min_age IN (&&age);
```

---

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-DAEF8542-1042-4F98-9C68-CED90AC42A79):

> ... SQL*Plus automatically DEFINEs any substitution variable preceded by two ampersands, but does not DEFINE those preceded by only one ampersand. When you have defined a variable, SQL*Plus will not prompt for its value in the current session.

If you only modify the second reference as you described in the question:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN (&age);
SELECT * FROM Job WHERE min_age IN (&&age);
```

then for the first query you will be prompted but the variable will not be defined; when the second query runs it will define the variable at that point but it has no value yet, so it has to prompt for one. Using `&&age` in the first query as well defines it then, and the first prompt stores the value, so it doesn't need to prompt for the second one.

Comment: This is the one! I'm actually frustrated because I was almost there.

I cannot upvote due to my points but thank you for taking the time to reply! Thanks so much.